# Prediction/Estimation of missing intervals inside Apache Kafka process

Tags: apache-kafka

Goal is to process raw readings (15min and 1h interval) from external remote meters (assets) in real time.

Process is defined using simple Apache Kafka producer/consumer and multiple Spring Boot microservices to deduplicate messages, transform (map) readings to our system (instead external codes insert internal IDS and similar stuff) and insert in TimescaleDB (extension of PostgreSql).

Everything seems fine, but there is requirement to perform real time prediction/estimation of missing intervals.

Simple example for one meter and 15 minute readings:

- On day 1 we got all readings. We process them and have them ingested in our DB.
- On day 2 we are missing all readings - so process is not even
  started for this meter.
- On day 3 we again got all readings - but only for day 3. Now we need
  to predict that whole day 2 is missing and create empty readings and
  then estimate them by some algorithm (that is not that important
  now).

My question here, is there any way or idea how to do this without querying existing database in one of the microservices and checking if something is missing?

Is it possible to check previous messages in Kafka topics and based on that do the prediction/estimation (kafka streams? - I don't get them at all) and is that even smart to do, or there is any other way/idea to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Personal opinion disclaimer

---

It is not reasonably possible to check previous messages in Kafka Streams. If you are hellbent on doing it, you could probably try to seek messages and re-consume them but Kafka will fight you every step on the way. The mental model is, that you are transforming or aggregating data that comes in in real time. If you need to query something about previous data, you ought to have collected that information when that data was coming through.

What could work (rather well even) is to separate the prediction of missing data from the transformation.

1. Create two consumers for the stream.
2. Have one topology (or whatever it is that does your transformations already) transform the data and load it back into Kafka and from there to timescaledb.
3. Have one topology (or another microservice) that does what is needed to predict missing data. Your usecase of backfilling a missing day could be handled by something like a count based on daily windows
4. Make that trigger your backfilling either as part of that topology or as a subsequent microservice and load that data to timescaledb as well.

Are you already using Kafka Streams for the transformations? This would be a classical usecase.

The recognition of missing data not so much

- As far as I understand it does not require high throughput. More the opposite. You want to know if there is no data.
- As far as I understand it latency is not a (main) concern.

Kafka Streams could be useful if you need to take automated action within seconds after data stops coming in. But even then, you could just write throughput metrics and trigger alerts in this case.

Pther than that, it is a very stateful problem and stream processing is at its best if you can treat every message separately reduce them in a "standard" manner like sums or counts.

I got the impression, that a delay of a few hours / a day is not that tragic and currently the backfilling might be done manually. In this case the cot of Kafka Streams would outweigh the benefits.

Comment: I don't use Kafka Streams, only standard Kafka topics with producers and consumers.

Latency is not main concern, main concern is that when big number of messages are coming that everything will break apart.

So I was thinking something like you suggested here, after transformations to send data to different topics, one for inserting in database, and second for predictions/estimations and that one could have maybe some batch listener so I can query all missing data from DB only once per batch (and reduce DB calls like that)? What do you think?

Comment: At least to me that sounds reasonable. :)